# Define sorts per group on Solr grouped search results

Tags: solr, lucene

When I query my Solr core I use grouping to determine upcoming items (based on a date) and items which are already available. For this I'm using a group query where I group the items by release_date. The problem is that I want to sort the upcoming items to sort by release_date asc, so the first available will turn up higher, and the released items by release date desc so the newest shows up higher;

```
http://solrcore.example/select?
  defType=edismax&
  group=true&
  group.query=optional_release_date:[1995-01-01T00:00:00Z%20TO%20NOW]&
  group.sort=optional_release_date%20asc&
  group.query=optional_release_date:[NOW%20TO%202200-01-01T00:00:00Z]&
  group.sort=optional_release_date%20desc&
  group.limit=50000&
  rows=2000
```

In the response I see that all groups are now only sorted asc.

```
"params": {
  "defType": "edismax",
  "group.sort": [
    "optional_release_date asc",
    "optional_release_date desc"
  ],
  "group.limit": "50000",
  "group.query": [
     "optional_release_date:[1995-01-01T00:00:00Z TO NOW]",
     "optional_release_date:[NOW TO 2200-01-01T00:00:00Z]"
  ],
  "rows": "2000",
  "group": "true"
}
```

Is there are proper way to define a sorting per group?